# Create a Spark Streaming Data Frame with the top n values from a column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

Currently i'm working with Spark 2.2.1 in Scala. Let's assume that i have a streaming Data Frame "streamDF". Then i have colCountsStreamDF which is:

```
val colCountsStreamDF=streamDF.groupBy($"colName").count()
```

How can i create a Streaming Data Frame that contains the "n" top counts?

I was trying with take(),head(),limit() but those either don't work with Streaming Data Frames or don't return a Streaming Data Frame.

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: How do you get `streamDF` ?

Comment: By using readStream on a path that will receive parquet files. 

    val streamDF = spark.readStream.schema(schema)
    .option("maxFilesPerTrigger",1)
    .parquet(path)

Comment: `val streamDF = spark.readStream.schema(schema) .option("maxFilesPerTrigger",1) 
.parquet(path)`